# tcsh auto-complete and getting the pattern for another autocompete

Tags: perl, autocomplete, csh, tcsh

Is it possible to get the match pattern so far with tc shell's complete?

What I mean is, assuming a command A, and execute:

```
A[TAB]
c1
c2
c3
```

A `c3[TAB]` <- here I want to complete to execute a command with the matched pattern so far: c3....

**Update:** Basically I'm trying to autocomplete from an XML.

```
    <xml>
      <key name="c1"></key>
      <key name="c2"></key>
      <key name="c3">
         <key name="c3-b2">
           <key name="c3-xdr"></key>
         </key>
      </key>
</xml>
```

so Basically I would like to be able to auto-complete like:
**c3[TAB]/c3-b2[TAB]/c3-xdr**

I'm currently trying to use `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` with **Perl**.

**and no, I cannot use Bash**

Comment: can you explain what you'd use it for?

Comment: @shx2 certainly, I would like to autocomplete from an XML file with a certain format.

Comment: can you give a concrete example? what's in the xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I'd go about it.  First, I'd use a simple xml-parsing script to print out the paths. Here's one I came up with (you can easily write one of your own using perl, or just use this one):

```
# xml_paths.py
import sys
from xml import sax

class PathHandler(sax.handler.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = []
    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name == 'key':
            self.path.append(attrs['name'])
            print '/'.join(self.path)
    def endElement(self, name):
        if name == 'key':
            self.path.pop()

sax.parse(sys.argv[1], PathHandler())
```

Finally, `complete` it (you should use absolute paths to the script and the xml file):

```
% complete A 'p#*#`python xml_paths.py a.xml`#'
% A <TAB>
c1              c2              c3              c3/c3-b2        c3/c3-b2/c3-xdr
% A c3/<TAB>
c3/c3-b2        c3/c3-b2/c3-xdr 
% A c3/c3-b2
```

For clarity, this is the output of the xml-parsing script:

```
% python xml_paths.py a.xml
c1
c2
c3
c3/c3-b2
c3/c3-b2/c3-xdr
```